# Расположить картинки в одну строку с сохранением пропорций и одинаковой высотой

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть картинки, которые хочу разместить В ОДНУ СТРОКУ НА ВСЮ ШИРИНУ ЭКРАНА так, чтобы высота картинок была одинакова ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНО ДРУГ ДРУГА на любых разрешениях, при этом каждая из них сохраняла свои пропорции: не сужались, не растягивались и примыкали друг к другу вплотную. И хотелось бы добиться кроссбраузерности - реально?
[ссылка на фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/6/)

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/598x396">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/488x396">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/605x396">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/756x396">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: можно добавить `max-height:нужная_высота` вместо `max-width`

Comment: @Umer а как же тогда быть с шириной? все картинки полностью не влезут...
https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/5/

Comment: Просто уберите бутстраповские классы и сделайте дивам обычный float:left

Comment: @Grundy и что из этого получится? не понимаю..
https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/8/

Comment: а зачем вы оставили max-width, если вам раньше посоветовали уже max-height? :-) [например](https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/9/) в принципе можно и обычным height обойтись

Comment: "в принципе можно и обычным height обойтись" @Grundy не, нельзя, т.к. нужно задействовать всю ширину экрана и так, чтобы картинки не соскакивали на 2ую строчку. задачка не такая простая, как кажется на первый взгляд

Comment: @Вася, кончено можно, у вас же одно из требований _высота картинок была одинакова_ при использовании _max-height_ она может отличаться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34235/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 1):

Итак, самое изящное **решение №1** (Спасибо @Grundy) - склеить все картинки в одну:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section: {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2447x396">
  </div>
</section>
```

[ответ 1](https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/20/)

**решение №2** без объединения без ie 8:
[ответ 2](https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/23/)
для ie 8 возможно подставить (на placehold.it проверить не удалось)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='img.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='img.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

**решение №3** со скриптом:
[ответ 3.1](https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/19/)
или
[ответ 3.2](https://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/17/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.pad-img {
    padding: 2px;
    float: left;        
    height: 50px;  
    // vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: нужно задействовать всю ширину экрана и так, чтобы картинки не соскакивали на 2ую строчку. задачка не такая простая, как кажется на первый взгляд

Comment: в % задайте ширину блока с изображением, чтобы задействовать всю ширину контейнера

Comment: @soledar10 поясните - для каждого изображения?

Comment: 4 изображения - значит ширина 25%

Comment: @soledar10, тогда у них может быть разная высота, в зависимости от начальных пропорций

Comment: @soledar10 да, или промежутки между друг другомhttps://jsfiddle.net/wzpy2d1p/14/

Comment: @Вася display flex используете? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/q44xu0a9/

Comment: @soledar10 если бы с полифилом каким для кроссбраузерности..

Comment: посмотрите здесь - https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: @soledar10 к сожалению полифил не спасает.. даже в  `edge` не работает для этого примера - показывает горизонтальную полосу прокрутки..

Comment: а такой вариант? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/2hg75js1/

Comment: @soledar10 не годится - промежутки между картинками и на малых разрешениях они съезжают на много строк